# Cannot install Appcelerator CLI - package wasn't found in unpacked tree

Tags: command-line-interface, appcelerator, appcelerator-cli

When trying to reinstall Appcelerator CLI (5.2.0 that is available today) I'm getting the following errors when running `npm install appcelerator -g`. What does that mean? I tried uninstalling the old version I had but did something still remain? (Tried `npm cache clear`but it didn't help)

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>node --version
v4.3.1

C:\>npm install appcelerator -g
npm WARN installMany request was bundled with appcelerator@4.2.3, but bundled pa
ckage wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany chalk was bundled with appcelerator@4.2.3, but bundled pack
age wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany progress was bundled with appcelerator@4.2.3, but bundled p
ackage wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany tar was bundled with appcelerator@4.2.3, but bundled packag
e wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany which was bundled with appcelerator@4.2.3, but bundled pack
age wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany debug was bundled with appcelerator@4.2.3, but bundled pack
age wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany lodash was bundled with appcelerator@4.2.3, but bundled pac
kage wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN installMany request was bundled with appcelerator@4.2.3, but bundled pa
ckage wasn't found in unpacked tree
C:\Users\Allan\AppData\Roaming\npm\appc -> C:\Users\Allan\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\appcelerator\bin\appc
C:\Users\Allan\AppData\Roaming\npm\appcelerator -> C:\Users\Allan\AppData\Roamin
g\npm\node_modules\appcelerator\bin\appc
appcelerator@4.2.3 C:\Users\Allan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appcelerator
├── which@1.0.8
├── progress@1.1.8
├── async@1.5.2
├── semver@3.0.1
├── debug@2.2.0 (ms@0.7.1)
├── chalk@0.5.1 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, ansi-styles@1.1.0, supports-color@0
.2.0, has-ansi@0.1.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0)
├── update-notifier@0.5.0 (is-npm@1.0.0, semver-diff@2.1.0, string-length@1.0.1,
 chalk@1.1.1, repeating@1.1.3, configstore@1.4.0, latest-version@1.0.1)
├── request@2.69.0 (aws-sign2@0.6.0, forever-agent@0.6.1, tunnel-agent@0.4.2, oa
uth-sign@0.8.1, caseless@0.11.0, is-typedarray@1.0.0, form-data@1.0.0-rc3, strin
gstream@0.0.5, isstream@0.1.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, extend@3.0.0, tough-co
okie@2.2.1, node-uuid@1.4.7, qs@6.0.2, combined-stream@1.0.5, mime-types@2.1.10,
 aws4@1.2.1, bl@1.0.3, hawk@3.1.3, http-signature@1.1.1, har-validator@2.0.6)
├── tar@1.0.3 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.8, fstream@1.0.8)
└── lodash@4.5.1
```

I also see Appcelerator updated https://web.appcelerator.com/product/cli to now mention Node version 4.3.1 - instead of some 0.x version. So I made sure I upgrade my Node to that same version.

PS. I'm getting quite tired on constant issues with app development. First I got away from Studio and was hoping CLI would solve the often occuring issues with updates, instability, silent fails, etc. It was running fine for while but now it is also making hickups...

Comment: The `appcelerator` NPM package is "just" an NPM package. So any errors there are likely to be issues with your NPM environment. Do other (global) packages install fine? Could you try to remove `npm uninstall -g appcelerator` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that you just need to ignore these warnings and run `appc setup` afterwards.

(What happened to the earlier answers? Why were they deleted?!)